# minimum cover of function dependency

Tags: database

I am a computer science student taking database module which is teaching normalisation and functional dependency now. then i faced this problem which i cant figure it out. please help if you have any idea.

Q:there is a relation R(A,B,C,D) with the set F of functional dependencies.

F = {{A}→{B}, {B}→{C}, {C}→{A}, {C}→{A,B}, {C,A,D}→{A,D}, {C}→{B} }

find minimal cover of F.

**Correct Ans: {{A}→{B}, {A}→{C}, {C}→{A},{B}→{A}}**

My procedure:

1st step: {C}→{A,B} can become {C}→{A} and {C}→{B} thus {C}→{A,B} is removed

2nd step: {C,A, D}→{A,D} can become {C, A, D}→{A} and {C, A, D}→{D}, but because {C}→{A}, {C, A, D}→{A} is removed and {C, A, D}→{D} become {C, D}→{D}

two steps make my answer become {{A}→{B}, {B}→{C}, {C}→{A},{C}→{B}, {C, D}→{D}}, but i cannot reach the correct Ans, anyone know how to proceed on? thanks

Comment: is this really how they teach normalisation?

Comment: hi, this is for functional dependency, for normalisation, they teach 2NF, 3NF and BCNF. Functional dependency and normalisation are under same topic in this module.

Comment: How can the correct answer omit the attribute 'D'?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: If the attribute D didn't appear on the right-hand side of any nontrivial FD, would it have to appear in a minimal cover?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is, um, incorrect.

> Correct Ans: {{A}→{B}, {A}→{C},
>   {C}→{A},{B}→{A}}

Since `{B}→{A}`, and `{A}→{C}`, can't you replace those two FDs with `{B}→{C}`?

And you can eliminate the attribute C from `{C, D}→{D}`, too, right?

Comment: it is correct answer provided by lecturer... but i dont know why

Comment: you are wrong. B->A ^ A->C implies B->C, But CAN NOT replace them.

Answer (score 0):

First, CAD->AD is trivial, cause if you know what are the value of CAD, obviously you know what are the values of AD.

So for now : F = {{A}→{B}, {B}→{C}, {C}→{A}, {C}→{A,B}, {C}→{B} }

Second, {C}→{A,B} is redundant as you mentioned.

so for now : F = {{A}→{B}, {B}→{C}, {C}→{A}, {C}→{B} }

Third, you can see that B exists in C+ on F-{C->B} therefore C->B is redundent.

so This is one of many minimal Covers for F : G = {{A}→{B}, {B}→{C}, {C}→{A} }

The Minimal Cover suggested by your proffesor is valid as well, Since there are no redundent dependencies in the set.

Comment: Where's D? Don't we need to cover all of R?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon: No we don't. {A,D}  is a subset of {C, A,D} So the dependency {C,A,D}→{A,D} can be generated by Armstrong axiom of reflexifity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong's_axioms